# Graph API Explorer Access Tokens vs. FB C# SDK Application Access Tokens

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk, access-token, facebook-access-token

The Graph API Explorer generates an access token which is typically 118 characters in length, whereas the token returned by FacebookOAuthClient().GetApplicationAccessToken() is far less, and has fewer rights to do things like execute FQL even with certain extended attributes selected.

Can anyone explain how I can obtain a token similar to the Graph API Explorer token using the FB C# SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Per the most current documentation for the C# SDK, they recommend getting the token using the Facebook JavaScript SDK using getLoginStatus() or login().  Then sending that access token over https by AJAX back to the server for the C# code to process and store in session (or other data store).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$app_id = "YOUR_APP_ID";
$app_secret = "YOUR_APP_SECRET";
$post_login_url = "http://YOUR_URL/THIS_FILE.php";

//Obtain the access_token with publish_stream permission 
if(empty($_REQUEST['code'])){ 
    $dialog_url= "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?"
. "client_id=" .  $app_id 
. "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url)
.  "&scope=publish_stream";
echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url 
. "'</script>");
}
else {
$code = $_REQUEST['code'];
$token_url="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
. "client_id=" . $app_id 
. "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url)
. "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
. "&code=" . $code;
$response = file_get_contents($token_url);
    $params = null;
    parse_str($response, $params);
    $access_token = $params['access_token'];

    setcookie("FBCode", $access_token);
}
?>
```

Was the working solution for me.
I'm saving my access_token in a cookie and parse it in my Silverlight 5 In-Browser App.